# Which is the best authentication method using for REST API in laravel?

Tags: api, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

Do I want to know about which is best? 
I had  googled this query and got much information from there ,Some of are 
CSRF,JWT,Auth0
Can you suggest  the best one ?

Comment: Use a `token based/stateless` auth mechanism, JWT/Auth0.

Comment: CSRF is not an authentication method. Json Web Tokens or Auth0 are authentication methods Auth0 is a service JWT you can pull a package. it all depends on your project you have to be more specific of your project requirements.

Answer (score 3):

As of 5.3, Laravel uses [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport)

> Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport,
>   which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel
>   application in a matter of minutes.

Prior to 5.3, or if you do not want to use Passport, you can have API Token Authentication [that way](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51).

Comment: Hi Wistar , I am using Laravel 5.1

Comment: @SumithSNair Then I suggest you use the link I provide in the answer. It worked well for my Laravel 5.2 RESTful API. (https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51). But, to be honest, I will upgrade to 5.3 because Passport is a much better feature